# a tags, checkboxes, and radio buttons not clickable on Mobile in Angular 1.4.9?

Tags: angularjs, mobile, input, clickable

I recently upgraded an app I work on to angular 1.4.9, with the hope of eventually migrating to 1.5 so that Angular 2 is an option as well.

I was startled though to find that when running on Android and iOS mobile devices, I couldn't select checkboxes or radio buttons, nor follow a tags with a tap!

Has anyone else encountered this??? Is there a workaround? I'm thinking about trying to just skip 1.4 and go directly to 1.5, hoping they fixed this.

Comment: Make sure you are loading the angular-touch.js and injecting ngTouch into your app module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is imperative that the corresponding version of ngTouch be in place for stuff like this. Running different versions of a variety of Angular modules in general is bad news bears (da-doi). Thanks Rob J